# Not able to communicate from a docker app to external database running outside docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a web application running within docker but the MYSQL  database is running on different host and port ( outside docker environment)
Its the legacy database and we have decided not to  migrate it to docker environment.

I am not able to telnet from within docker shell to MYSQL  host/port
Can any one help me with an example docker-compse.yml showing how an app within docker can connect to an external MYSQL or any service running on an external host and port.

Comment: Can you connect to the port from outside of a docker container on the docker host?

Comment: yes I can telnet to the external server from the host where my docker is running. In fact I can Ping from docker shell to external host but cant telnet as I cant reach the external port